# Non- Conference Panel Presentation?

Tags: cv, social-science

I'm part of a panel presentation for some undergrad students who are part of a multi-institutional summer scholarship program. The panel is about paths through grad school in our field (I'm a PhD student).

Would you put this on a CV somewhere, or is that really padding out the CV? I'm in Social Science.

Answer (score 1):

I gave about a dozen talks in various seminar series while a graduate student. These were valuable practice in giving presentations and eventually my thesis defense presentation mirrored some of these talks.

None of these went on my CV. If you have more involvement in this program than just sitting on one panel maybe you could list it as mentorship activity but I would not list it as an academic talk about your research.

Comment: Great, thank you. This was my suspicion, but I wanted some confirmation. I'm a fellow with this organization, so I suppose that is sufficient CV recognition.

Comment: The last paragraph is especially valuable. Mentorship is a valuable attribute and practice for any academic.